# SQL query, store result of SELECT in local variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

I create a query with some results reused. I search a way to put the result into a variable and use it.

A simple way to see what I want something looking like this - I want this:

```
DECLARE @result1 ?????

SET @result1 = SELECT a,b,c FROM table1
SELECT a AS val FROM @result1
UNION
SELECT b AS val FROM @result1
UNION
SELECT c AS val FROM @result1
```

Not this :

```
 SELECT a AS val FROM (SELECT a,b,c FROM table1)
 UNION
 SELECT b AS val FROM (SELECT a,b,c FROM table1)
 UNION
 SELECT c AS val FROM (SELECT a,b,c FROM table1)
```

It's not the result of this query that I'm concerned with, but instead:

1. to stop selecting the result so many times - in my sample, I reselected the table 3 times
2. the query of `@result1` is usually so much more complex. So, with a variable, the code will be cleaner.

Maybe I want to much - or there's a type of local variable. Or using the type table and set data inside.

What do you suggest me?

Thank you

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can create table variables:

```
DECLARE @result1 TABLE (a INT, b INT, c INT)

INSERT INTO @result1
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table1

SELECT a AS val FROM @result1
UNION
SELECT b AS val FROM @result1
UNION
SELECT c AS val FROM @result1
```

This should be fine for what you need.

Answer (score 26):

Here are some other approaches you can take.

**1. CTE with union:**

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT a, b, c FROM table1)
SELECT a AS val FROM cte
UNION SELECT b AS val FROM cte
UNION SELECT c AS val FROM cte;
```

**2. CTE with unpivot:**

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT a, b, c FROM table1)
SELECT DISTINCT val
FROM cte
UNPIVOT (val FOR col IN (a, b, c)) u;
```

Comment: with cte seems interesting. dont need to create table of each row. tank you

Comment: @AnthonyFaull thanks to answer. But, how about an `in(statement)` statement?

Answer (score 11):

Isn't this a much simpler solution, if I correctly understand the question, of course.

I want to load email addresses that are in a table called "spam" into a variable.

```
select email from spam
```

produces the following list, say:

```
.accountant
.bid
.buiilldanything.com
.club
.cn
.cricket
.date
.download
.eu
```

To load into the variable @list:

```
declare @list as varchar(8000)
set @list += @list (select email from spam)
```

@list may now be INSERTed into a table, etc.

I hope this helps.

To use it for a .csv file or in VB, spike the code:

```
declare @list as varchar(8000)
set @list += @list (select '"'+email+',"' from spam)
print @list
```

and it produces ready-made code to use elsewhere:

```
".accountant,"
".bid,"
".buiilldanything.com,"
".club,"
".cn,"
".cricket,"
".date,"
".download,"
".eu,"
```

One can be very creative.

Thanks

Nico

Answer (score 6):

I came here with a similar question/problem, but I only needed a single value to be stored from the query, not an array/table of results as in the orig post.  I was able to use the table method above for a single value, however I have stumbled upon an easier way to store a single value.

`declare @myVal int;
set @myVal = isnull((select a from table1), 0);`

Make sure to default the value in the isnull statement to a valid type for your variable, in my example the value in table1 that we're storing is an int.

Comment: You can also do that with `select @myVal = a from table1` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples